# Python 3 Efficient Dynamic Dictionary Grouping

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a rather large JSON output that I want to re-categorize.

I have a series of loops to do what I want.

I was wondering, if there is a more efficient way to do what I'm doing?

Here's what I'm doing ...

Grab the json blob

```
nodes = self.getNodes()
data =  json.loads(nodes)
```

Temporary list for creating the groups ...

```
group_list = list()
```

Construct the dictionary ...

```
# I avoid the shorthand form for legibility
group_dict = dict()
group_dict['all'] = dict()
group_dict['all']['hosts'] = list()
group_dict['all']['vars'] = list()
```

Loop 1: Appending a list of groups ...

```
for l in data:
  if '-' not in l['hostname']:
    g = re.split('[0-9]+',l['hostname'],flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
    group_list.append(g)
```

Get unique values ...

```
group_list = sorted(set(group_list))
```

Loop 2: Populate `group_dict` with groups dictionaries ...

```
for group in group_list:
  group_dict[group] = dict()
  group_dict[group]['hosts'] = list()
  group_dict[group]['vars'] = list()
```

Loop3: Populate node names into the correct group dictionary ...

```
for n in data:
  if '-' not in n['hostname']:
    grp = re.split('[0-9]+',n['hostname'],flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
    group_dict[grp]['hosts'].append(n['hostname'])
```

Return indented JSON blob ...

```
return json.dumps(group_dict,indent=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make two passes over the data when you only need one.

```
nodes = self.getNodes()
data =  json.loads(nodes)

group_dict = {}

for n in data:
  if '-' not in n['hostname']:
    grp = re.split('[0-9]+',n['hostname'],flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
    group_dict.setdefault(grp, {'hosts':[], 'vars':[]})
    group_dict[grp]['hosts'].append(n['hostname'])

return json.dumps(group_dict,indent=1)
```

Or using `defaultdict` which is preferable to `setdefault` when the default is a more complex object rather than an empty list or dictionary for which CPython keeps free objects pools as the argument to `defaultdict` is called when the value of a missing key is needed:

```
from collections import defaultdict

nodes = self.getNodes()
data =  json.loads(nodes)

group_dict = defaultdict(lambda: {'hosts':[], 'vars':[]})

for n in data:
  if '-' not in n['hostname']:
    grp = re.split('[0-9]+',n['hostname'],flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
    group_dict[grp]['hosts'].append(n['hostname'])

return json.dumps(group_dict,indent=1)
```